# Rails and jquery customizing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am quite new to ruby on rails development and I have question about customizing jquery-ui in rails application.

I know that now to install jquery-ui one need to use special gem "jquery-ui-rails" and then using

```
/*
*= require jquery.ui.all
*/
```

in code

But how am I going to customize that jquery-ui? For example, I need to make changes in jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js. What is the correct way to do it?

1. It is considered bad style to modify jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js
2. In case you need to modify jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js, you DO NOT need to include "jquery-ui-rails" gem and need to include them manually
3. Some special way to customize them?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure on how to properly utilise jQuery-UI within a rails environment so unfortunately I can't help with that, but with your second issue the easiest way to customise jQuery-UI's CSS is to use the [theme-roller that they provide](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

I would imagine that the gem repository is the standard version and you would have to replace the CSS files with those created by the theme-roller within the installation directory but I am not sure on this.